# msaccess sort order

Tags: ms-access, sorting

I probably am missing something very simple here, but I cannot see it. MSAccess is sorting strangely, to test this I have created a simple one text field table and inserted these values:

1. BB0-01
2. BB001-0
3. BB0-01a

Now, according to little old me, since BB0-01 and BB0-01a have the first 6 characters in common, and BB001-0 already deviates at the 4th, the -01 and -01a should be sorted close to each other, something like:

1. BB0-01
2. BB0-01a
3. BB001-0

But they are not. The sorted order is as in the first list, with the -0 in between the -01 and -01a. Reverse sorting puts the -01a at position #1 but the -0 stays in between them. How can this be?

Comment: This article may be of interest : http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/443068-general-sort-order. MS offer a fairly clunky ASCII sort order solution here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the sorting disregards -

Can't find anything in the MS Access doc that says anything about it though.

Comment: [This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/troubleshoot-sorting-HP005188128.aspx) notes »Some expressions might make two different values the same or equal, for sorting purposes. For example, if an expression ignores the minus sign preceding negative values, -3 and 3 might appear together, in the order they were originally entered.« – sorting seems to be quite customizable and might need some tweaking here. The OP might do well to remember that not all cultures sort the same anyway so his preferred sort order might not be the one Access is using.

Comment: Sorting difference between cultures is one thing. But my MSAccess runs in US English mode and it still seems to make A-3 into A3. I replaced all the minusses with equal signs and then sorting is ok. So it indeed seems to ignore minuses in the middle of strings